# How to convert xml into hierachical table by xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

Anyone know how to convert XML into a table of hierachy using XSLT? I have been working on it for hours and do not know how to do that.Sample xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
<h1>
    <value1>1</value1>
    <h2>
        <value2>2</value2>
        <h3>
            <value3>3</value3>
            <value3>3</value3>
            <value3>3</value3>
        </h3>
    </h2>
    <h2>
        <value2>2</value2>
        <h3>
            <value3>3</value3>
            <value3>3</value3>
            <value3>3</value3>
        </h3>
    </h2>
</h1>
<h1>
    <value1>1</value1>
    <h2>
        <value2>2</value2>
        <h3>
            <value3>3</value3>
            <value3>3</value3>
            <value3>3</value3>
        </h3>
    </h2>
    <h2>
        <value2>2</value2>
        <h3>
            <value3>3</value3>
            <value3>3</value3>
            <value3>3</value3>
        </h3>
    </h2>
</h1>
</table>
```

And the output will like this:

```
    1  2   3
           3
           3
       2   3
           3
           3
    1  2   3
           3
           3
       2   3
           3
           3
```

PS:each number is in a cell and there are 12 rows totally. The number 1 spans 6 rows and number 2 spans 3 rows.

Comment: Please show us your XSLT stylesheet. Especially, if you've been working on it for hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for HTML output so `<td colspan="...">` on the first row and the corresponding columns omitted entirely for the subsequent rows in the span, then:

- You want one `<tr>` per `value3`, and you always need the third column.
- If this `value3` is the first `value3` within its parent `h2` then you also need to precede it with the `value2`,
- and if *that* `value2` is the first `h2` within its `h1` then you need to precede it with the `value1`.

```xml
<xsl:template match="table">
  <table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//value3" />
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value3">
  <tr>
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::value3)">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::h2[1]" />
    </xsl:if>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h2">
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::h2)">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::h1[1]" />
  </xsl:if>
  <td rowspan="{count(.//value3)}"><xsl:value-of select="value2" /></td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1">
  <td rowspan="{count(.//value3)}"><xsl:value-of select="value1" /></td>
</xsl:template>
```

The `rowspan` attributes are easy because your XML is nicely nested - the span is always the number of descendant `value3` elements under this `h1` or `h2`.